# can't upload csv file with cyrilic data to google data studio - encoding utf-8 error

Tags: encoding, utf-8, looker-studio

Basic Googling revealed I should save my file as CSV file. I did and uploaded again - the error is still there:

```
This file has processing errors.
Row 2: Invalid characters in the file. Only UTF-8 encoded characters are supported.
```

Some columns have Cyrillic names, "address", "name".

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What's the objective (CSV or to get the data to Google Data Studio)?
- If the aim is to load the data from the Excel file to Google Data Studio, there are two approaches:

## 1) CSV UTF-8

Was the file saved as a CSV or was it **specifically encoded as a UTF-8 CSV** (images from [Dear Systems, 2019](https://support.dearsystems.com/support/solutions/articles/11000075350-how-to-save-the-csv-file-in-unicode-csv-as-utf-8-in-microsoft-excel))?

**Step 1**:

[image: Step 1]

**Step 2**:

[image: Step 2]

**Step 3**:

[image: Step 3]

## 2) Google Sheets

- Load the Excel file (as is) to Google Drive;
- Open the Excel file in Google Drive and save as a Google Sheet;
- Use the Google Sheet as the Data Set when creating the [Data Source](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6295223) and subsequently the Google Data Studio Report.

## Update with a GIF

- Tried it out with a 7 Mb Excel File from [SampleDocs](http://www.sampledocs.in/)
- [Excel File on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G8OR5x6hq3fY7rGzK1Vb3puIcE5g7vu9/view?usp=sharing)
- [Google Sheets File (from Excel File)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BWH5XesAIPCY5BCLULsqrUBWQpLeQ6vrtcG4PSX_qZg/edit?usp=sharing)
- The process (**Load** Excel file, **Convert** it to a Google Sheet and **Load** all 50,000 rows) took under 45 seconds:

[image]

- Alternatively, you could Copy from Excel and Paste in Google Sheets:

  - Select All (Excel): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
  - Copy (Excel): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
  - Paste Values (Google Sheets): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>